# Получить файл по URL

Tags: java, url

В библиотеке есть функция, которая прикладывает файл к сообщению, код из документации выглядит следующим образом

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(
            "delivery.zip");
    MessageFile file1 = new MessageFile();
    file1.setContent(stream);
    file1.setName("delivery.zip");
```

Что делать, если файл нужно скачать из `URL`?

Если передать в `FileInputStream` строковую переменную, которая содержит ссылку до файла, то появляется исключение `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 4):

Используйте класс [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) вместо `File`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.site.com/file.txt");
InputStream stream = url.openStream();
```